Which Church tradition (or denomination) can actually demonstrate unbroken Apostolic succession?
Many Church traditions claim unbroken Apostolic succession such as Eastern Orthodox, Anglican, Roman Catholic, and others.  It seems as though there are gaps in the successions of some of these traditions where they are delineated.
Can any Church tradition or denomination actually demonstrate unbroken Apostolic succession or are there gaps in every account making them all just claims with varying degrees of 'proof'?

when you say demonstrate unbroken Apostolic succession do you mean just a list of the succession?

Such a 'succession' will be a list of names of persons. What matters is the being built on the foundation that was originally laid. Deviating from that foundation, generation by generation, results in an un-founded (spiritual) collapse : despite the 'succession' continuing by tradition.

@NigelJ That may be your definition, but that's not necessarily how the traditions which value Apostolic succession may define it. For example, the Catholic Church recognizes Apostolic succession both in its own hierarchy and in others as well, even where those groups/individuals may be considered heretics.

@eques said " the Catholic Church recognizes Apostolic succession both in its own hierarchy and in others as well, even where those groups/individuals may be considered heretics."  Don't believe that CC would recognize a group that is heretical as having apostolic succession.  Can you name at least one example?

They can all provide lists of names, but is that really proof?

No one can. Many Catholic/Orthodox churches claim to using various rationales, but as you note, there are gaps lost in history.

@SLM The point is that apostolic succession and orthodoxy are two separate values. Apostolic succession is defined as a line of validly ordained bishops. It is possible to ordain bishops validly while teaching some form of heresy. The easiest example would be the Old Catholics (Union of Utrecht).

@Dúthomhas the problem is your framing the question is not quite how those groups who teach it would describe it. Apostolic succession is not demonstrated precisely by the list of names, but by the practice of episcopal consecration validly and continually.

@eques yes, see my answer that distinguishes between a physical lineage and teach the same.

@SLM and you are not making the same distinction I was making and which I explained in my comment above to you.

I know nothing of the history of Christianity, but two that came to mind as candidates would be the Coptic Church of Egypt (St. Mark) and the Syro-Malabar Church of Kerala in Southern India (St. Thomas). The latter seems more fuzzy.

@eques So one must not only provide a list of names but also provide evidence that each of those individuals was validly consecrated to the episcopate?

@eques Point of view makes a difference here. OP seems to reject framing it as those who teach it would frame it; as I read the question, it is: is there an actual and verifiable list of names leading back to one of Christ’s apostles? — to which the answer is “no”, not unless you accept some additional premise that bridges that gap.

@Dúthomhas OP says demonstrates proof of unbroken succession. You have interpreted that to mean list of verifiable names to the exclusion of any other type of proof.

@MikeBorden If succession is only through bishops, you have to provide some evidence the people named were bishops.


OP: Can any Church tradition or denomination actually demonstrate unbroken Apostolic succession or are there gaps in every account making them all just claims with varying degrees of 'proof'?

As others mentioned, different denominations will be able to at least provide a listing of physical people purporting to show a valid lineage from apostle to bishop and onward to the present.
Other denominations, however, may say that apostolic succession is not about a physical lineage, much like a blood lineage familiar to the priests shown in a Levitical priesthood, but rather apostolic succession is about faithful men who "teach the same".

And the things that thou hast heard of me among many witnesses, the same commit thou to faithful men, who shall be able to teach others also. 2 Tim 2:2

Either way one defines it, the earliest records are somewhat foggy, but to use Irenaeus, we find this.


It is within the power of all, therefore, in every Church, who may wish to see the truth,  Against Heresies Book III Chapter III


To note, there is one Body, but there is "every Church", which in that time were noted by geography.
With that in mind, here is Irenaeus' lineages.


Since, however, it would be very tedious, in such a volume as this, to reckon up the successions of all the Churches


Clearly enough, he is telling us that they all taught the same, they all had valid apostolic succession.  He then mentions three (see same letter).
The church at Rome whose first successor after the apostles (Peter and Paul) was Linus.
The church at Smyrna and all Asiatic churches (John to Polycarp).
The church at Ephesus (Paul to not listed in letter).
About the same time circa 200AD, Tertullian also commented about lineages and, to note, the all-important "teach the same" (the steadfastness of agreeing with the original apostles).

But if there be any (heresies) which are bold enough to plant themselves in the midst of the apostolic age, that they may thereby seem to have been handed down by the apostles, because they existed in the time of the apostles, we can say: Let them produce the original records2181 of their churches; let them unfold the roll of their bishops, running down in due succession from the beginning in such a manner that [that first bishop of theirs2182] bishop shall be able to show for his ordainer and predecessor some one of the apostles or of apostolic men,—a man, moreover, who continued stedfast with the apostles.  The Prescription Against Heretics Chapter XXXII

Tertullian then mentions two specific churches at Smyrna and Rome.  But note the contradiction about the successor at Rome.

For this is the manner in which the apostolic churches transmit2183 their registers:2184 as the church of Smyrna, which records that Polycarp was placed therein by John; as also the church of Rome, which makes Clement to have been ordained in like manner by Peter.2185 In exactly the same way the other churches likewise exhibit (their several worthies), whom, as having been appointed to their episcopal places by apostles, they regard as transmitters of the apostolic seed. IBID

The church at Smyrna (John to Polycarp).
The church at Rome (Peter to Clement).
To circle back to my earlier comment that apostolic succession has everything to do with "teach the same" and basically not much to do with a physical lineage, as Tertullian points out.

To this test [of apostolicity], therefore will they be submitted for proof2187 by those churches, who, although they derive not their founder from apostles or apostolic men (as being of much later date, for they are in fact being founded daily), yet, since they agree in the same faith, they are accounted as not less apostolic because they are akin in doctrine.

In short, though not part of the OP, the "teach the same" must obviously arise out from "it is written".

This seems like the catholic side of things, a more formal way. Definitely better then my answer which was just "well here is an example"

" but rather apostolic succession is about faithful men who "teach the same"." who claims that?

@eques I quoted Paul, Irenaeus, and Tertullian on the subject.

That's actually not what he says. Tertullian is saying that heretics should show the records that their teaching comes from the Apostles (i.e. use apostolic succession to prove their claim); he's not saying succession exists because one teaches the same. Further again, I asked who teaches the claim that Apostolic succession consists in a doctrinal adherence, not a succession. Tertullian even says "ordains" and "transmitters of apostolic seed" so he is viewing a succession line there.

Tertullian quoted: "To this test, therefore will they be submitted for proof2187 by those churches, who, although they derive not their founder from apostles or apostolic men (as being of much later date, for they are in fact being founded daily), yet, since they agree in the same faith, they are accounted as not less apostolic because they are akin in doctrine."   NOT FOUNDED, YET AGREE IN THE SAME FAITH.  APOSTOLIC BECAUSE AKIN IN DOCTRINE.

Irenaeus: "we are in a position to reckon up those who were by the apostles instituted bishops in the Churches, and [to demonstrate] the succession of these men to our own times; those who neither taught nor knew of anything like what these [heretics] rave about."  JUST BECAUSE YOU KNEW AN APOSTLE, THE TEST IS TEACHING THE SAME AS AN APOSTLE.   Even the CC would agree that ordained priests and popes and patriarchs can fall away.  Why?  Teaching heresy.

Most orthodox churches will be able to provide a complete list. Here is an example of an Orthodox church apostolic succession in full form. It has no blank periods where the church "died" or anything like that. It starts in Constantinople and is present in America present day.
The Church of Constantinople (1-99 people, by Name and Episcopal term)

Andrew, the Apostle of our Lord
(Founded the Church at Constantinople; ordained Stachys)    Founded 38 AD
Stachys, the Disciple (one of the 70 Apostles)
(First Bishop of Constantinople)    AD 38 – 54
Onesimos AD 54 – 68
Polykarpos   AD 69 – 89
Ploutarchos  AD 89 – 105
Sedekion AD 105 – 114
Diogenes AD 114 – 129
Eleftherios  AD129 – 136
Felix    AD 136 – 141
Polykarpos II   AD 141 – 144
Athenodoros AD 144 – 148
Euzoios AD 148 – 154
Laurentios  AD 154 – 166
Alypios AD 166 – 169
Pertinax    AD 169 – 187
Olympianos  AD 187 – 198
Markos I    AD 198 – 211
Philadelphos    AD 211 – 214
Kyriakos I  AD 214 – 230
Kastinos    AD 230 – 237
Eugenios I  AD 237 – 242
Titos   AD 242 – 272
Dometios    AD 272 – 303
Roufinos    AD 303
Provos  AD 303 – 315
Metrophanes I   AD 315 – 325
Alexandros  AD 325 – 340
Paulos I, the Confessor AD 340 – 41, 342 – 34, 348 – 50
Eusebios    AD 341 – 342
Makedonios I    AD 344 – 348, 350 – 360
Eudoxios    AD 360 – 369
Demophilos  AD 369 – 379
Evagrios    AD 379
Maximos I,  AD 380
Gregory, the Theologian
(First Archbishop of Constantinople)    AD 379 – 381
Nectarios   AD 381 – 397
John I, the Chrysostom  AD 398 – 404
Arsakios    AD 404 – 405
Attikos AD 406 – 425
Sisinios I  AD 425 – 427
Nestorios   AD 428 – 431
Maximianos  AD 431 – 434
Proklos AD 434 – 447
Flavianos   AD 447 – 449
Anatolios
(First Patriarch of Constantinople) AD 449 – 458
Gennadios I AD 458 – 471
Akakios AD 471 – 489
Favritas (Fravitas) AD 489 – 490
Euphemios   AD 490 – 496
Makedonios II   AD 496 – 511
Timotheos I AD 511 – 518
John II, the Cappadocian    AD 518 – 520
Epiphanios  AD 520 – 536
Anthimos    AD 535 – 536
Menas   AD 536 – 552
Eutychios I AD 552 – 565, 577 – 582
John III    AD 566 – 577
Eutychios II    AD 577 – 582
John IV, the Faster AD 582 – 595
Kyriakos II AD 595 – 607
Thomas I    AD 607 – 610
Sergios I   AD 610 – 638
Pyrros I (later returned as Pyrros II)  AD 638 – 641
Paulos II   AD 641 – 652
Pyrros II ()same as Pyrros I)   AD 652 or 654
Petros  AD 652 – 664
Thomas II   AD 665 – 668
John V  AD 668 – 674
Constantine I   AD 674 – 676
Theodoros I AD 676 – 678, 683 – 686
Georgios I  AD 678 – 683
Paulos III  AD 686 – 693
Kallinikos I    AD 693 – 705
Kyros   AD 705 – 711
John VI AD 711 – 715
Germanos I, the Confessor   AD 715 – 730
Anastasios  AD 730 – 751
Constantine II  AD 754 – 766
Niketas, the Slav   AD 766 – 780
Paulos IV   AD 780 – 784
Tarasios    AD 784 – 806
Nikephoros I    AD 806 – 815
Theodotos, Melissenos   AD 815 – 821
Antonios I, Kasymatas   AD 821 – 826
John VII the Grammatikos    AD 826 – 842
Methodios I, the Confessor  842 – 846
Ignatios I, the Prince  AD 846 – 857, 867 – 878
Photios the Great   AD 857 – 867, 878 – 886
Stephanos I, the Prince AD 886 – 893
Antonios II, Kavleas    AD 893 – 895
Nikolaos I, the Mystic  AD 895 – 906, 911 – 925
Euthymios I AD 906 – 911
Stephanos II    AD 925 – 928
Tryphon AD 928 – 931
Theophylctos, Lakapenos, the Princeling AD 933 – 956
Polyeuctos  AD 956 – 970
Vasilios I, Skamandrenos    AD 970 – 974
Antonios III, Skandalios, also Stoudites    AD 974 – 980
Nikolaos II, Chrysoverges  AD 984 – 995


The Russian Church
Period during which the Metropolitans sat at Kiev:

Michael, the Syrian  A.D. 990
Leontius A.D. 993
John A.D. 1015
Theopemptus  A.D. 1037
Hilarion A.D. 1051
George   A.D. 1072
John II  A.D. 1080
John III A.D. 1089
Ephraim  A.D. 1096
Nicholas    A.D. 1098
Nicephorus  A.D. 1108
Nicetas A.D. 1124
Michael II  A.D. 1127
Clement A.D. 1197
Constantine A.D. 1136
Theodore    A.D. 1160
John IV A.D. 1164
Constantine II  A.D. 1167
Nicephorus II   A.D. 1185
Matthew A.D. 1201
Kyrill I    A.D. 1205
Joseph  A.D. 1240

Period during which the Metropolitans sat at Vladimir:

Kyrill II   A.D. 1250
Maximus A.D. 1283
Peter   A.D. 1308

Period during which the Metropolitans resided at Moscow:

Theognostes A.D. 1328
Alexis  A.D. 1353
Cyprian A.D. 1380
Photius A.D. 1410
Isidore A.D. 1432
Jonah   A.D. 1448
Theodosius  A D. 1462
Philip I    A.D. 1467
Gerontius   A.D. 1472
Zosimus A.D. 1491
Simon   A.D. 1496
Barlaam A.D. 1511
Daniel  A.D. 1522
Joasaph A.D. 1539
Macarius    A.D. 1542
Athanasius  A.D. 1564
Philip  A.D. 1565
Cyrill III  A.D. 1568
Anthony A.D. 1572
Dionysius   A.D. 1582

The Patriarchs of Moscow:

Job  A.D. 1587
Hermogenes   A.D. 1606
Philaret A.D. 1620
Joasaph I    A.D. 1631
Joseph   A.D. 1642
Nikon    A.D. 1653
Joasaph II   A.D. 1667
Pitirim  A.D. 1672
Joachim  A.D. 1673
Adrian  A.D. 1690
Metropolitan Stephen (Yavorsky), of Rostov, Guardian of the Patriarchate    A.D. 1701
The Most Holy Synod A.D. 1721 – 1918
St.Tikhon the New Martyr, 11th Patriarch    A.D. 1918 – 1925
St. Peter the New Martyr, Metropolitan of Petrograd,
Locum Tenens of the Patriarchal Throne  A.D. 1925 – 1938

The Russian Orthodox Church Outside of Russia

Blessed Metropolitan Anthony (Khrapovitsky)   A.D. 1920 – 1936
Blessed Metropolitan Anastassy (Gribanovsky)  A.D. 1936 – 1964
St. Philaret (Voznesensky) the Confessor, of New York A.D. 1964 – 1985
Metropolitan Vitaly (Ustinov)    A.D. 1986 – 1994

Russian Orthodox American Church

Metropolitan Valentine of Vladimir and Sudzal 1990 – 2012

GOCA (Genuine Orthodox Church of America) Chief Hierarchs:

Archbishop Gregory of Denver and Northern America 2001 – present


There are some small "potential gaps" where years don't overlap but generally this is a very impressive list. Were each individual on the list ordained to the episcopate by their predecessor or by some common predecessor?

Who exactly ordained each subsequent listed person gets more fuzzy over time as multiple bishops would have co-existed at the same time with varying responsibilities, during various lifespans it is not unreasonable for some of the people on this list to be either one or the other situation that you brought up. Also this is a list of "heads of the church" through history. If I went into more depth, I'd find who was in the Synod from 1721 to 1918. But I hope that my answer helps with your question. Yes there are churches that can demonstrate it.

Take for example your 54 and 55: Anthimos was deposed as an alleged monophysite/ miaphysite, including by his successor Menas. Or your 76 and 77: Germanos I was deposed or forced to resign by the Emperor during the iconaclasm controversy and replaced by the more flexible Anastasios.  Neither of these were continuity.

@Henry it would be a bit dishonest for us to assume that for 54, 55, 76 and 77 that these people were the "only" bishop. After 500 years the tree would have "branched" many many times. If I replaced those 4 men with 4 other men who were also bishops in that time without those blemishes would the list be satisfactory?

The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints believe they have an unbroken* Apostolic succession.
The LDS do believe that there was a Great Apostasy

The Apostles were killed, and priesthood authority—including the keys to direct and receive revelation for the Church—was taken from the earth.

that took many years.
* The above being said the LDS also believe in the Restoration of the Priesthood:

While Joseph Smith and Oliver Cowdery were working on the translation of the Book of Mormon, they read about baptism for the remission of sins. On May 15, 1829, they went to a wooded area near Joseph’s home in Harmony, Pennsylvania, and prayed about what they had learned.
In answer to their prayer, John the Baptist, under the direction of the Lord Jesus Christ, appeared and conferred upon them the Aaronic Priesthood, saying, “Upon you my fellow servants, in the name of Messiah I confer the Priesthood of Aaron, which holds the keys of the ministering of angels, and of the gospel of repentance, and of baptism by immersion for the remission of sins.” Following John’s instructions, Joseph and Oliver then baptized each other and ordained each other to the Aaronic Priesthood.
Sometime after John the Baptist’s appearance, the ancient Apostles Peter, James, and John also appeared to Joseph and Oliver, again under the direction of Jesus Christ, and conferred upon them the Melchizedek Priesthood. “The Melchizedek Priesthood holds the right of presidency, and has power and authority over all the offices in the church in all ages of the world, to administer in spiritual things.” With this authority again on the earth, the Church of Jesus Christ could be restored in its fulness.

Latter-day prophets can be traced then from Peter, James, and John to Joseph Smith all the way to the current (2024) prophet Russell M Nelson.
You can find a list of apostles (quorum of the twelve) on Wikipedia, with current ones here
